# Why can the "Community" bot approve suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently came across [this suggested edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/144451), which I had rejected for being insubstantial. When I later looked at how others had reviewed the edit, I saw that the [Community user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) apparently approved this edit.

A screenshot of the page is here:

[image: Image showing the Community user approving an edit]

According to the user description, the community bot does:

> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions

This mentions owning suggested edits from anonymous users, but the edit was from [JohnDoea](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/123574/johndoea), not an anonymous user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993):

> #### A reviewer either improves an edit, or rejects and replaces it with a different edit
>
> When one is reviewing suggested edits, there are five available buttons, two of which allow the reviewer to edit the post themselves:
>
> [image: Approve, Improve Edit, Reject and Edit, Reject, Skip]
>
> If the reviewer chooses "Improve Edit" and submits their improved form of it, the suggested edit is approved by Community (and immediately replaced by the improved one). If the reviewer chooses Reject and Edit, Community rejects the suggestion and provides a detailed message:
>
> [image: This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.]

hft chose to "Improve Edit", so the Community user approved JohnDoea's edit and hft's edit was added after that.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it all. Though I have to say, that system is **not** intuitive **at all**.